# Laravel 8: How to change Uri

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a link like this:

`<a href="question/{{$notification->data['thread']}}">Link</a>`

And I have set this route for `question/{id}` uri:

`Route::get('question/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'changeUri']);`

And the Method `changeUri` goes like this:

```
public function changeUri($id)
{
    $show = Question::where('id', $id)->first();

    $this->showQuestion($show->slug);
}
```

As you can see, I have called `showQuestion` method which is another method written in the same `Controller` and goes here:

```
public function showQuestion($slug)
{
    $show = Question::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('questions.question',[
        'show' => $show,
    ]);
}
```

And finally that `question.blade.php` shows the result via this route:

```
Route::get('questions/{slug}', [QuestionController::class, 'showQuestion'])->name('show.question');
```

So the point here is to change the uri from `question/{id}` to `questions/{slug}`, so then the above route will run.

Now the problem with this is that, when I click on that link, it shows me an empty screen... I mean no error and result at all!

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue? Is there any better way for changing uri?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this with me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
$this->showQuestion($show->slug);
```

inside **changeUri** method

you can redirect like

```
return redirect()->route('show.question', ['slug' => $show->slug]);
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel 8 set that route:

```
<a href="{{route('question',$slug->id)}}">Link</a>
```